# MySQL - Joining three tables to get the SUM of a column

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has 3 tables. 1st table hosts the users id and position. The 2nd table hosts the boss/squire id. The 3rd hosts the squire id and its money. Suppose I am table1.id=1. I am a pos1 with 2 squire, table1.id=2 with pos1 and table1.id=3 with pos1, where in this 2 has squires under them. table1.id=4 with pos2 and table1.id=5 with pos3 is both under table1.id=2. Same with table1.id=3.

```
table1.id=1 ------> table1.id=2 ------> table1.id=4
            |                   |
            |                   |
            |                   ------> table1.id=5
            |
            ------> table1.id=3 ------> table1.id=6
                                |
                                |
                                ------> table1.id=7
```

I want the result be

sumTotal = 1000

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (`id` INT, `pos` VARCHAR(255))
CREATE TABLE Table2 (`id` INT, `id_boss` INT, `id_squire` INT)
CREATE TABLE Table3 (`id` INT, `id_squire` INT, `money` INT)

INSERT INTO Table1 (`id`, `pos`)
VALUES
(1, 'pos1'),
(2, 'pos1'),
(3, 'pos1'),
(4, 'pos2'),
(5, 'pos2'),
(6, 'pos3'),
(7, 'pos3');

INSERT INTO Table2 (`id`, `id_boss`, `id_squire`)
VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 3),
(4, 2, 4),
(5, 2, 5),
(6, 3, 6),
(7, 3, 7);

INSERT INTO Table3 (`id`, `id_squire`, `money`)
VALUES
(1, 4, 100),
(2, 5, 200),
(3, 6, 300),
(4, 7, 400);
```

I will be using table1.id=1

to help understand pls click: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8924/4/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need a self join to `Table2` so that you get the descendant nodes:

```
SELECT SUM(money)
FROM Table2 AS t21
JOIN Table2 AS t22 ON t21.id_squire = t22.id_boss
JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON t22.id_squire = t3.id_squire
WHERE t21.id_boss = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8924/9)

**Edit:**

If you want to also include `Table1` in the query then you can put it at the beginning of the `JOIN` chain:

```
SELECT SUM(t3.money)
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t21 ON t1.id = t21.id_boss
JOIN Table2 AS t22 ON t21.id_squire = t22.id_boss
JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON t22.id_squire = t3.id_squire
WHERE t1.id = 1
```

Comment: Hi, the code is ok but I want to use table1.id=1 in WHERE. My reason is that I have other filters in table1 that I didnt post just to make the problem easier to explain. Like table1.pos=pos2 something like that. THanks

Comment: It worked now, thanks. I did put table1 but after table3. It didnt give me what i need. Thanks!